# Entity Framework's Where statement with whitespaces at the end

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use Where statement for retrieving data from the database and it's always returning data if whitespaces are added at the end of the string, so

```
.Where(p => p.Username == "sysadmin")
```

and

```
.Where(p => p.Username == "sysadmin      ")
```

both are returning data (I expect the second one to return null). And the same thing is with `WebSecurity.Login` method, it is logging in succesfully in both cases.

Comment: Just Use p.Username.Trim() method to solve this problem

Comment: You may need to add a check that the string lengths match as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [reason](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626) why it is doing like that is:

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, ,
>   General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI
>   standard requires padding for the character strings used in
>   comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. The
>   padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause
>   predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example,
>   Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent
>   for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

You can try to do as:

```
.Where(p => p.Username.Trim() == "sysadmin")
```

Comment: A little more info about the `.Trim()` method and its conversion to SQL: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17424594/261050)